# how to make some text not editable by user in Jtextpane?

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am using Jtextpane in my application. I required to add some tags like
[PKG-MEDIA] in jtextpane.
I want user to not edit this tag, while he can edit other text in jtextpane.

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    JFrame j = new JFrame("Hello!");
    j.setSize(200, 200);
    JTextPane k = new JTextPane();
    k.setFont(new Font("Akshar Unicode Regular", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    k.setText("this is a test code [PKG-MEDIA]. I want to make this tag [PKG-1234] not editable");
    j.add(k);
    j.setVisible(true);
    j.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `DocumentFilter`. You can check whether in sert (or remove) is allowed in the position edit happens

See for example [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0260__Swing-Event/CustomDocumentFilter.htm)

Answer (score 4):

To achieve this effect, you need to implement `StyledDocument` (try to extend `DefaultStyledDocument`). In there, maintain a list of text sections that aren't editable and refuse to change them inside of `insertString()` and `remove()`

For example, when the `offset` is inside one of the uneditable ranges, just return from `insertString()` without making a change.

When the user tries to delete text, only remove text around the protected ranges in `remove()`